# How to drop oldest SQL server database automatically?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way using script to drop the oldest SQL server database?

The requirement is that using the SSIS package I have to drop SQL server database which is 50 months old. Suppose the current month is 2016-11-30 and there is a database which is 50 months old, e.g., `Sales_Backup_2011_10_30_443240_542456`. The script should drop this oldest database. Similarly, when the current month is 2016-12-31 the script should drop `Sales_Backup_2011_11_30_544556_753577`, and so on.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean "oldest database"? It sounds like you tried to emulate partitioning by creating multiple databases instead of eg multiple tables, multiple filegroups. Assuming "oldest" means "whose name parses to an old date", query `sys.databases`, extract the date using string operations and select only database names with old dates

Comment: Which database version are you using? Parsing a string is a lot easier eg in SQL Server 2014 than it was in 2005.

Comment: BTW, SQL Server 2016 allows partitioning [even in the Express edition](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1). You may want to rethink your design

Comment: Clean up some of the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.databases` in the `MASTER` database has a `create_date` field you could use. You can query that one and use a `DATEDIFF` to get the database names you want to drop.

> **create_date**   *datetime*: Date the database was created or renamed. For
>   tempdb, this value changes every time the server restarts.

See MSDN documentation for more info about this table: [sys.databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I have used below script to do automatically. in this where do I need to add Datetime?  DECLARE Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)  = ''
    -- Populate Qry.
    SELECT  top 1
        Qry = Qry 
            + 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) 
   + ' DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) 
   
    FROM    
        sys.Databases d
    WHERE   
        d.[State] =0 
        AND LOWER(d.Name) <> 'tempdb'
   ORDER BY create_date DESC
    ;

/* Enable the first line to run.
 * Disable the bottom line, when you are happy with the script.
 */
--EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @Qry --@BKUScript
SELECT @Qry;

Comment: sorry with out using create_date is there any other way? because the create_date is not in correct date order for the databases.